# Clipping shaded areas to a curve boundary

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I am trying to draw the following graph, but I failed to achieve it.

[image]

What is wrong with this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.86}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.86}
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}{ \draw [black] (0,\incrmnty*\y) node [left, xshift=-.1cm] {\aff} -- +(180:.12);}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\x*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}{ \draw [black] (\incrmnty*\x,0) node [below, yshift=-.25cm] {\aff} -- +(-90:\incrmntx*.2);}
\draw [very thick, blue, looseness=.9] (0,0) to [out=15, in=-110] node [pos=.0] (ao) {} node [pos=.08] (aw){} node [pos=.146] (ah) {} node [pos=.24] (af) {} node [pos=.306] (av) {} node [pos=.4] (ax) {} node [pos=.484] (as) {} node [pos=.58] (ag) {} node [pos=.704] (an) {} node [pos=.8] (at) {} node [pos=1.] (aa) {} (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\draw [very thick, red!70!black, looseness=1] (0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\path[clip] (0,0)  to [out=15, in=-110] (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!65!white] (aa.center) node [black, xshift=.36cm, yshift=-3.cm] {} |- (aa.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (aa.center);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!60!white] (at.center) node [black, xshift=.36cm, yshift=-3.cm] {$\bf A_10$} |- (at.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (at.center) -| (at.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!55!white] (an.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.4cm] {$\bf A_9$} |- (an.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (an.center) -| (an.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!50!white] (ag.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.cm] {$\bf A_8$} |- (ag.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (ag.center) -| (ag.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!45!white] (as.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.46cm] {$\bf A_7$} |- (as.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (as.center) -| (as.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!40!white] (ax.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.2cm] {$\bf A_6$} |- (ax.center|-0,0)-- (0,0) --   (ax.center) -| (ax.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!35!white] (av.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.9cm] {$\bf A_5$} |- (av.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (av.center) -| (av.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!30!white] (af.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.68cm] {$\bf A_4$} |- (af.center|-0,0)-- (0,0) --   (af.center) -| (af.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!25!white] (ah.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.4cm] {$\bf A_3$} |- (ah.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (ah.center) -| (ah.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (aw.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.16cm] {$\bf A_2$} |- (aw.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) -- (aw.center) -| (aw.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (ao.center) node [black, xshift=.8cm, yshift=0cm] {$\bf A_1$} |- (ao.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) -- (ao.center) -| (ao.center-|0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It generated the following drawing

[image]

The following comments should be fulfilled

1. the shaded areas should be confined below the blue curve, to the
   x-axis.
2. there should be no line connecting the nodes on the blue curve with
   position (0,0).
3. the relations to y60 and y20 are not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Martin Scharrer's nice answer but with loops to make the code shorter. (And yes, the `looseness` was missing in the clip path.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.86}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.86}
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}
{ \draw [black] (0,\incrmnty*\y) node [left, xshift=-.1cm] {\aff} -- +(180:.12);}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\x*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}
{ \draw [black] (\incrmnty*\x,0) node [below, yshift=-.25cm] {\aff} -- +(-90:\incrmntx*.2);}
\draw [very thick, blue] (0,0) to [out=15, in=-110, looseness=.9] 
coordinate [pos=.0] (ao)  coordinate [pos=.08] (aw) coordinate [pos=.146] (ah)  
coordinate [pos=.24] (af)  coordinate [pos=.306] (av)  coordinate [pos=.4] (ax)  
coordinate [pos=.484] (as)  coordinate [pos=.58] (ag)  coordinate [pos=.704] (an)  
coordinate [pos=.8] (at)  coordinate [pos=1.] (aa)  (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\draw [very thick, red!70!black, looseness=1] (0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[clip,postaction={draw,green,line width=1mm}] (0,0)  
to [out=15, in=-110, looseness=.9] (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10) |- cycle;
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(12-\Y)}] in {aa,at,an,ag,as,ax,av,af,ah,aw,ao}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fullness}{70-5*\Y}
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!\fullness!white]
(0,0) -- (\X.center) |-  cycle ;}
\end{scope}
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(11-\Y)}] in {at,an,ag,as,ax,av,af,ah,aw,ao}
\draw [thick] (\X.center|-0,0) |- (\X.center-| (0,0)node[pos=0.25,right]{$\boldsymbol{A_{\Z}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all very very much. Both (Martin Scharrer/marmot) and (AndréC) codes gave me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You need to place the clipping path into the scope, not before it, and close the clipping path with e.g. `|- cycle` or similar. Also you should need the same parameters as with the actual line. The `looseness` value was missing.

This solves points 1 and 2 of your list. I don't understand what you mean with point 3.

I also fixed your `A_10` which needs to be written as `A_{10}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.86}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.86}

\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);

\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*10)] in {0,2,4,...,10}{
    \draw [black] (0,\incrmnty*\y) node [left, xshift=-.1cm] {\aff} -- +(180:.12);
}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\x*10)] in {0,2,4,...,10}{
    \draw [black] (\incrmnty*\x,0) node [below, yshift=-.25cm] {\aff} -- +(-90:\incrmntx*.2);
}

\draw [very thick, blue, looseness=.9] (0,0) to [out=15, in=-110] 
    node [pos=.0] (ao) {}
    node [pos=.08] (aw){}
    node [pos=.146] (ah) {}
    node [pos=.24] (af) {}
    node [pos=.306] (av) {}
    node [pos=.4] (ax) {}
    node [pos=.484] (as) {}
    node [pos=.58] (ag) {}
    node [pos=.704] (an) {}
    node [pos=.8] (at) {}
    node [pos=1.] (aa) {}
    (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);

\draw [very thick, red!70!black, looseness=1] (0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path [clip, looseness=.9] (0,0) to [out=15, in=-110] (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10) |- (0, -1) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=green!65!white] (aa.center) node [black, xshift=.36cm, yshift=-3.cm] {X} |- (aa.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (aa.center);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!60!white] (at.center) node [black, xshift=.36cm, yshift=-3.cm] {$\bf A_{10}$} |- (at.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (at.center) -| (at.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!55!white] (an.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.4cm] {$\bf A_9$} |- (an.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (an.center) -| (an.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!50!white] (ag.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.cm] {$\bf A_8$} |- (ag.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (ag.center) -| (ag.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!45!white] (as.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.46cm] {$\bf A_7$} |- (as.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (as.center) -| (as.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!40!white] (ax.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.2cm] {$\bf A_6$} |- (ax.center|-0,0)-- (0,0) --   (ax.center) -| (ax.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!35!white] (av.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.9cm] {$\bf A_5$} |- (av.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (av.center) -| (av.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!30!white] (af.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.68cm] {$\bf A_4$} |- (af.center|-0,0)-- (0,0) --   (af.center) -| (af.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!25!white] (ah.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.4cm] {$\bf A_3$} |- (ah.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) --  (ah.center) -| (ah.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (aw.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.16cm] {$\bf A_2$} |- (aw.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) -- (aw.center) -| (aw.center-|0,0);
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (ao.center) node [black, xshift=.8cm, yshift=0cm] {$\bf A_1$} |- (ao.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) -- (ao.center) -| (ao.center-|0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I was confused which to accept as an answer; but marmot`s code was shorter.

Answer (score 3):

I have to go to work, I will come back this afternoon to explain the code if you need it. Sorry.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{.86}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{.86}
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}{ \draw [black] (0,\incrmnty*\y) node [left, xshift=-.1cm] {\aff} -- +(180:.12);}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\x*10)]in {0,2,4,...,10}{
            \draw [black] (\incrmnty*\x,0) node [below, yshift=-.25cm] {\aff} -- +(-90:\incrmntx*.2);
            }
            \draw [very thick, blue, looseness=.9] (0,0) to [out=15, in=-110] node [pos=.0] (ao) {} node [pos=.08] (aw){} node [pos=.146] (ah) {} node [pos=.24] (af) {} node [pos=.306] (av) {} node [pos=.4] (ax) {} node [pos=.484] (as) {} node [pos=.58] (ag) {} node [pos=.704] (an) {} node [pos=.8] (at) {at} node [pos=1.] (aa) {} (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
            \draw [very thick, red!70!black, looseness=1] (0,0) -- (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
            \path[clip] (0,0)  to [out=15, in=-110] (\incrmntx*10,\incrmnty*10);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!65!white] (aa.center |- 0,0)--(aa.center)  --(at.center) |- (at.center |- 0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!60!white] (at.center) node [black, xshift=.36cm, yshift=-3.cm] {$\bf A_10$} --(an.center) |-(at.center |- 0,0) --cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!55!white] (an.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.4cm] {$\bf A_9$} -- (ag.center)|- (an.center|- 0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!50!white] (ag.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-2.cm] {$\bf A_8$} --(as.center) |- (ag.center|-0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!45!white] (as.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.46cm] {$\bf A_7$} --(ax.center)|- (as.center|-0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!40!white] (ax.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-1.2cm] {$\bf A_6$} -- (av.center)|- (ax.center|-0,0)-- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!35!white] (av.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.9cm] {$\bf A_5$} --(af.center)|- (av.center|-0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!30!white] (af.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.68cm] {$\bf A_4$} --(ah.center)|- (af.center|-0,0)-- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!25!white] (ah.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.4cm] {$\bf A_3$} --(aw.center)|- (ah.center|-0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (aw.center) node [black, xshift=.28cm, yshift=-.16cm] {$\bf A_2$} --(ao.center)|- (aw.center|-0,0) -- cycle;
%\draw [thick, black!80!white, fill=black!20!white] (ao.center) node [black, xshift=.8cm, yshift=0cm] {$\bf A_1$} |- (ao.center|-0,0) -- (0,0) -- (ao.center) -| (ao.center-|0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Both your code and marmot`s are working fine. I was confused which to accept as an answer; but marmot`s code was shorter.

Comment: @Hany It is preferable to accept answers whose code is understood. Not for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Thank you AndréC for your answer. I agree with you. Your code is simpler and more understood. Both your answer and marmot`s answer are very good; and I was very confused which one to accept as an answer and which one as useful. I hope that the administrators can find a way to accept 2 answers. N.B. I added the next line for each node to draw the horizontal lines (\draw [thick, black!40!white] (at.center) -| (at.center-|0,0);) which you did not mention, but I figured it out. Again thank you very much for your effort and time. I learned very much from your answers to my previous questions.

Comment: @Hany You have not fully understood how this site works. You can wait several days before accepting an answer. And this is recommended by tex.stackexchange. This allows you to analyze each answer calmly, to ask for additional explanations. Take the time to analyze the answers. In addition, it allows others to answer later and ensures that your answer has been read by more people.

Comment: Let me see. You have the `0` of the `10` in `A_{10}` displaced, an undesired `at` floating around, no explanation whatsoever, no attempt to shorten the code. Is this why you feel your answer is better than the others?

Comment: @AndréC Thank you for your comment. I will take this in consideration in the future.

Comment: @marmot I have never claimed that my answer is better than the others. I affirm that choosing an answer according to the length of its text is an aesthetic choice that does not have to take place.